# strange character inserted in table utf8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, utf-8

I have a site developed in codeigniter where I'd like to insert a record inside my database in a table with utf8 fields.
The problem is that when I insert something inside the table I see that:

```
�"�h�t�t�p�:�/�/�I�m�a�g�e�1�.�u�r�l�f�o�r�i�m�a�g�e�s�.�c�o�m�/�D�e�f�a�u�l�t�/�8�8�0�4�/�2�3�6�9�2�2�6�2�-�1�8�4�3�3�8�5�2�6�6�.�j�p�g�"�
```

There are many more characters. The real string is a simple path. I don't know the format of the string because it is from an external server.

This is my query to insert record. I take the string from xml and if I print it inside the page I see the correct string.  The problem occurs whenever I check inside the database:

```
foreach($img->childNodes as $node){
     $data = array(
         'image'=>$node->getAttribute('path'),
     );
     $this->db->insert('hotel_images',$data);
}
```

Comment: Can you check the string's encoding with [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)? Then try to convert it with [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is not UTF-8. It is UCS-2 or UTF-16. UCS-2 is a subset of UTF-16, so treating it as UTF-16 should do the trick.

You can convert it using [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

```
$data = iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $data);
```